# How many different ways are there to place the order if the employee orders at least three cases of each variety?

Tags: combinatorics

An employee of a grocery store is placing an order for soda. There are 8 varieties
of soda and they are sold in cases. Each case contains only one variety of soda.
The store will order 50 cases total. How many different ways are there to place the
order if the employee orders at least three cases of each variety?

**My attempt**

I used pigeon hole principle and got the answer as

$3(50-1)+1$ $=148$ $ways$

Can anyone please verify whether this is correct or not

Comment: Problems in which you are counting arrangements should be tagged with combinatorics.  Your answer is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is incorrect.

Since there must be at least three cases of each of the eight varieties of soda in the order, the employee only has a choice of which $50 - 3 \cdot 8 = 50 - 24 = 26$ additional cases to order.  Let $x_k$ be the number of additional cases of variety $k$ that the employee opts to order.  Then
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 + x_7 + x_8 = 26$$
is an equation in the nonnegative integers.  A particular solution of the equation corresponds to the placement of seven addition signs in a row of $26$ ones.  For instance,
$$1 1 1 1 + 1 1 1 + 1 1 + + 1 1 1 1 1 + 1 1 1 1 1 1 + 1 1 + 1 1 1 1$$
corresponds to the solution $x_1 = 4$, $x_2 = 3$, $x_3 = 2$, $x_4 = 0$, $x_5 = 5$, $x_6 = 6$, $x_7 = 2$, $x_8 = 4$.  The number of such solutions is 
$$\binom{26 + 7}{7} = \binom{33}{7}$$
since we must choose which $7$ of the $33$ positions required for $26$ ones and $7$ addition signs will be filled with addition signs.

Comment: Can you please explain me the last step

Comment: There are $33$ symbols, of which $7$ are addition signs and $26$ are ones.  A solution is determined by choosing which $7$ of the $33$ positions are filled with addition signs.

Comment: Did you use any formula like $C(n+r-1,r)$

Comment: I implicitly used that formula.  Notice that if we choose which $26$ of the $33$ positions are filled with ones, we get $$\binom{33}{26} = \binom{26 + 8 - 1}{26} = \binom{26 + 8 - 1}{8 - 1} = \binom{33}{7}$$  In this case, $n = 8$ and $r = 26$.

Comment: Ohhh, this is really complicated. Can you explain how did you get the values for $x1$,$x2$,$x3$,$x4$,$x5$,$x6$,$x7$,$x8$

Comment: Remember that $x_k$ represents the number of additional cases of the $k$th variety of soda that the employee orders.  Therefore, it is a nonnegative integer.  Thus, the number of ways the employee can order the soda is the number of solutions of the equation $$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 + x_7 + x_8 = 26$$ in the nonnegative integers.

Comment: Then what about the values that were assigned to the $xk's$

Comment: The values are determined by the positions of the addition signs.  Take a look at the example above.